# Javascript to detect domain forwarding?

Tags: javascript, dns, forwarding

I own too many domains!

I'm looking to sell some off but don't want to spin up a page for each and every one of them.

I would like to build one page, and have all of my unused domains forward to that page.

ex: a.com, b.com, and c.com all forward to 
"buymydomains.biz"

I would like to log which domain forwarded to my for sale site:
"user types in a.com and is forwarded to buymydomains.biz, and JS logs the fact that they got there from navigating to a.com"

I've tested out `document.referrer`

and it is coming back as the empty string.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you going to log this from the client-side?

Comment: why redirect? just respond with the same page for every domain and use `window.location`.